# How to put POST form data in action

Tags: php, api, post

I am trying to setup a user creation API for VestaCP. I have these two pages.

The form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br>
Email Address:<br>
<<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then the action:

```
<?php
// Server credentials
$vst_hostname = 'MYSERVERADDRESS';
$vst_username = 'MYSERVERUSERNAME';
$vst_password = 'MYSERVERPASSWORD';
$vst_command = 'v-add-user';

// New Account
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$email = 'email'; 
$package = 'Free';
$fist_name = 'Null';
$last_name = 'Null';

// Prepare POST query
$postvars = array(
'user' => $vst_username,
'password' => $vst_password,
'returncode' => $vst_returncode,
'cmd' => $vst_command,
'arg1' => $username,
'arg2' => $password,
'arg3' => $email,
'arg4' => $package,
'arg5' => $fist_name,
'arg6' => $last_name
);
$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);

// Send POST query via cURL
$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://' . $vst_hostname . ':8083/api/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$answer = curl_exec($curl);

// Check result
if($answer == 0) {
echo "User account has been successfuly created\n";
} else {
echo "Query returned error code: " .$answer. "\n";
}
?>
```

I think the problem is inputting the form data into the php script but I'm not very experienced so I don't know.

The API is connecting to my server correctly as I tested the same

```
//Server Credentials
```

part with a different API and it worked.

When I run this script, it outputs "User account has been successfully created" but when I check my control panel, there is no new user.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I only wrote the form, this script was made by VestaCP as shown here: https://vestacp.com/docs/api/. The errors in this script are direct from Vesta.

Comment: Shouldn't `$username = 'username';` be `$username = $_POST['username'];`? And `$fistname` ??

Comment: I would recommend you to overthink your script. You're doing things you don't need to do or you do twice. Go over it, line to line.

Comment: @frz3993 I did not write this script, it is from VestaCP as seen here https://vestacp.com/docs/api/ the error was written by the creator.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Once again I did not write this script and do not really understand it.

Comment: @frz3993 any idea on how to fix this script? If not i'll go check ask this on the Vesta Forums.

Comment: @cdg if the PHP script you posted along with your question is the `process.php`. You should replace the `'username'`, `'password'` and `'email'` with `$_POST` variables. `$_POST['username']`, `$_POST['password']` and `$_POST['email']` respectively. The $_POST will contain all the variables sent from the form to the PHP script. Indexed by the input name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="username">
<br>
Firstname:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="password">
<br>
Email Address:<br>
<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
// Server credentials
$vst_hostname = 'MYSERVERADDRESS';
$vst_username = 'admin';
$vst_password = 'ADMINPASSWORD';
$vst_returncode = 'yes';
$vst_command = 'v-add-user';

// New Account
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$package = 'default'; // $package = 'Free'; //Free package exist on server?
$fist_name = $_POST['firstname']; 
$last_name = $_POST['name']; 

// Prepare POST query
$postvars = array(
'user' => $vst_username,
'password' => $vst_password,
'returncode' => $vst_returncode,
'cmd' => $vst_command,
'arg1' => $username,
'arg2' => $password,
'arg3' => $email,
'arg4' => $package,
'arg5' => $fist_name,
'arg6' => $last_name
);
$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);

// Send POST query via cURL
$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://' . $vst_hostname . ':8083/api/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$answer = curl_exec($curl);

// Check result
if($answer == 0) {
echo "User account has been successfuly created\n";
} else {
echo "Query returned error code: " .$answer. "\n";
}
?>
```